# What is the difference between MDM and third party services for distributing the app from Enterprise Developer Program?

Tags: ios, developer-program

am asking this because I really need to explain it to my client. My client wants to distribute apps only to his employees for business purposes, like in-house application. He wants the feature like TestFlight which is acting like App Store where we can update the app and install the app every time the developer update the app. He doesn't want to submit his app to App Store. In order to make his employees to use easily, he also said, his employees can install the app easily and show the update easily like Testflight without expire date or limited testers. I found hockey app , but it requires testers to be Hockeyapp members.

Any Help?

Answer (score 1):

[Mobile Device Management (MDM)](https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/mdm-software) or [Mobile Application Management (MAM)](https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/mobile-application-management/) solutions can be used to distribute in-house apps to the employees. For this, they'll need to enroll the employees' devices in MDM or MAM. After this, they can upload in-house apps to the MDM console and bulk push to the enrolled devices. It is also possible to distribute apps that are in the App Store.

Can you make it clear what you told about TestFlight, as I didn't catch it? You said "He wants the feature like TestFlight", but TestFlight is an independent service (MDM do not come with TestFlight). Head on to the section 'TestFlight Beta Testing' in [this article](https://www.hexnode.com/blogs/enterprise-app-distribution/) and you'll learn more about it.

The app that distributed through TestFlight is the 'beta app' which have a life of 60 days for each build. On the other hand, 'in-house apps' have an infinite lifetime.

If you need to know anything from me, leave a comment. I am happy to help.